# Issues with DateTime.AddMinutes() in Dynamic LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, entity-framework-4

I'm currently running into an issue using LINQ->Entites w/ Entity Framework v 4.2 and a T4-generated object context.  I am relatively informed on how LINQ queries are converted into store expressions before being executed against the database, but am by no means an expert.  From what I understand, the .NET functions used are converted to their equivalents in T-SQL, and those that do not have equivalents (for example, `String.Format()`) will throw a `System.NotSupportedException` at run time.

In my dynamic LINQ query, I'm using `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes()` to filter out my result set:

```
public void ExecuteSearch()
{
   var timeElapsedTresholdInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TimeElapsedThresholdInMinutes") );

   var resultSet = ( from entity in _dbContext.EntityCollection
                     where /*non-date-related where clause stuff*/
                           && 
                           entity.DateAdded <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1 * timeElapsedThresholdInMinutes)
                     select entity);

   /* do something with resultSet */
}
```

At run time, I am getting `System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method DateTime.Now.AddMinutes() method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Say for example, my timeElapsedThreshold has a value of -30 after being evaluated.  Does anyone know why this wouldn't map to `DATEADD(MINUTE,-30,GETDATE());`?  Is there something I'm missing here?

Granted, I can turn my code into:

```
public void ExecuteSearch()
{
   var maxDateTimeThreshold = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes( -1 * Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TimeElapsedThresholdInMinutes"));

   var resultSet = ( from entity in _dbContext.EntityCollection
                     where /*non-date-related where clause stuff*/
                           && 
                           entity.DateAdded <= maxDateTimeThreshold
                     select entity);
}
```

and overcome the issue of my code breaking, but I'd really like to understand why LINQ->Entities considers `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes()` as a .NET method that has no T-SQL equivalent.  Any help / feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LINQ Expression translates into under laying data source language, in your case its `SQL`, and in LINQ to Entities `DateTime.AddMinutes` doesn't have any implementation which would translate the query to corresponding equivalent in SQL. That is why .Net framework provided.

```
System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes
```

You should see: [Date and Time Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx)

You can have your query as:

```
   var resultSet = ( from entity in _dbContext.EntityCollection
                     where /*non-date-related where clause stuff*/
                           && 
                           entity.DateAdded <= 
                          System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(
                                 DateTime.Now, -1 * timeElapsedThresholdInMinutes)
                     select entity);
```

But in your case its better if you can calculate the value before hand, like in your second code sample, since that will avoid the conversion for every record.

Comment: This has been moved to `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions`.   `[Obsolete("This class has been replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.")]`

Answer (score 5):

EntityFunctions is obsolete (EF 6.x).

Please use [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) class for DateTime manipulations.

e.g from cmd in context.Commands where cmd.ExecutedOn > DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds(baseDate, millisecondsToAdd) select cmd

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the `DbFunction` for long time, until today I realized...why do I even need to bother with that `DbFunction` at all.

And here is what came to my mind:

```
var dateLimit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20);
var result = db.TableName.Where(x => x.MyDateTime > dateLimit);
```

I just took the `'AddMinutes'` operation out of the linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd really like to understand why LINQ->Entities considers DateTime.Now.AddMinutes() as a .NET method that has no T-SQL equivalent

Because every mapping from .NET to T-SQL has to be manually implemented, and they just didn't implement this one...

Comment: Fair enough. Just seems like this mapping would be too obvious to miss, but then again, I'm not Microsoft.